# Dynamically set asp:TableRow positions based on dropdown selection

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

```html
<div id="div1" runat="server">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server" border="0" CssClass="SupplierFormTable" HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="100%">
                <asp:TableHeaderRow>
                    <asp:TableHeaderCell HorizontalAlign="Left" ColumnSpan="8">       Approval Sequence        </asp:TableHeaderCell>
                </asp:TableHeaderRow>
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell Width="22%">
                     1.
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="drpdwnlst_Seq1" runat="server" Width="35%" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="--select--" Value="-1"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell Width="22%">
                    2.
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="drpdwnlst_Seq2" runat="server" Width="35%" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="--select--" Value="-1"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell Width="22%">
                    3.
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="drpdwnlst_Seq3" runat="server" Width="35%" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="--select--" Value="-1"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell Width="22%">
                    4.
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="drpdwnlst_Seq4" runat="server" Width="35%" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="--select--" Value="-1"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell Width="22%">
                    5.
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="drpdwnlst_Seq5" runat="server" Width="35%" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="--select--" Value="-1"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell Width="22%">
                    6.
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="drpdwnlst_Seq6" runat="server" Width="35%" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="--select--" Value="-1"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
            </asp:Table>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

I have this table inside a div tag.

```html
<div id="div_Approvals" runat="server">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Table ID="tbl_Approvals" runat="server" border="0" CssClass="SupplierFormTable" HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="100%">
                <asp:TableHeaderRow>
                    <asp:TableHeaderCell HorizontalAlign="Left" ColumnSpan="8">
                     Approval                                             
                    </asp:TableHeaderCell>
                </asp:TableHeaderRow>

                <asp:TableRow  >
                    <asp:TableCell Width="22%">
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl_HiringManager" Text="Hiring Manager :"></asp:Label>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="drpdwnlst_HiringManagerName" runat="server" Width="35%"></asp:DropDownList>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_HiringManagerSignature" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_HiringManagerDate" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell></asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_HiringManagerComment" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:Button ID="btn_HiringManagerApprove" Text="Approve" runat="server" OnClick="btn_HiringManagerApprove_Click" />
                        <asp:Button ID="btn_HiringManagerReApprove" Text="Re-Approve" runat="server" OnClick="btn_HiringManagerReApprove_Click" Visible="false" />
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow >
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl_ReportingGroupExecutive" Text="Reporting Group Executive :"></asp:Label>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="drpdwnlst_ReportingGroupName" runat="server" Width="35%"></asp:DropDownList>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_ReportingGroupExecutiveSignature" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_ReportingGroupExecutiveDate" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell></asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_ReportingGroupExecutiveComment" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:Button ID="btn_ReportingGroup_Approve" Text="Approve" runat="server" OnClick="btn_ReportingGroup_Approve_Click" />
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl_ProgramOrProjectOwner" Text="Program/Project Owner (if applicable) :"></asp:Label>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="drpdwnlst_PPO_Name" runat="server" Width="35%"></asp:DropDownList>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_ProgramOrProjectOwnerSignature" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_ProgramOrProjectOwnerDate" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell></asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_ProgramOrProjectOwnerComment" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:Button ID="btn_PPO_Approve" Text="Approve" runat="server" OnClick="btn_PPO_Approve_Click" />
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl_Finance" Text="Finance"></asp:Label>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="drpdwnlst_Finance" runat="server" Width="35%"></asp:DropDownList>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_FinanceSignature" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_FinanceDate" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell></asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_FinanceComment" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:Button ID="btn_Finance_Approve" Text="Approve" runat="server" OnClick="btn_Finance_Approve_Click" />
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl_PresidentAndCOO" Text="President & COO (if applicable) :"></asp:Label>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="drpdwnlst_PresidentAndCoo_Name" runat="server" Width="35%"></asp:DropDownList>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_PresidentAndCOOSignature" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_PresidentAndCOODate" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell></asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_PresidentAndCOOComment" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:Button ID="btn_PresidentAndCoo_Approve" Text="Approve" runat="server" OnClick="btn_PresidentAndCoo_Approve_Click" />
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl_HR" Text="Human Resources :"></asp:Label>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="drpdwnlst_HR_Name" runat="server" Width="35%"></asp:DropDownList>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_HRSignature" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_HRDate" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell></asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_HRComment" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="100%"></asp:TextBox>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:Button ID="btn_HR_Approve" Text="Approve" runat="server" OnClick="btn_HR_Approve_Click" />
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
            </asp:Table>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

The requirement is that based on the dropdown selection, I want to change positions of the TableRow of table **tbl_Approvals**.

How to achieve this as I cannot use a `<div>` inside `<asp:Table>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it were me I would create the different styles I would want as CSS classes then when the index changes for your drop down list change the class attribute for the table (or row which ever makes sense) using:

```
 [object id].Attributes.Add("style", "someCssClass;");
```